# React js src attribute is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Component Img that receives an image file. The component reads the file and puts a base64 result into my `state.base64` variable.

When I `forceUpdate` the state and log the values, the result is there, but in browser it looks empty. Here is my code.

[Jsbin code](http://jsbin.com/rafikopelu/2/edit)

Comment: your jsbin is missing an "app" id in the HTML.
`<div id=app></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the code:

```javascript
return (
  <img src={this.state.base64} {...this.props} />
);
```

If you log `this.props`, you'll see there is a `src` prop with a value of `null`. So, `{...this.props}` is overwriting the explicit `src` prop you're setting.

You can either change the order so the more specific props come last:

```javascript
return (
  <img {...this.props} src={this.state.base64} />
);
```

or create an object from `this.props` with the `src` attribute removed.

See http://jsbin.com/rutokutemi/2/edit for a working example.